# Microsoft Botframework custom enum

Tags: enums, botframework, chatbot

Hello I'm using Microsoft Botframework.
And I want to make a custom enum and if user selected other he will enter an option that is not existed in the list.

```
Please select value: 
1-option1 
2-option2  
3-other
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with FormFlow's FieldReflector's .SetActive :

```
[Serializable]
public class OptionalFormFlow
{
    public enum Options
    {
        Option1 = 1,
        Option2 = 2,
        Other = 3
    }

    public Options Option { get; set; }
    public string OtherOption { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static IForm<OptionalFormFlow> BuildForm()
    {

        var built = new FormBuilder<OptionalFormFlow>()
            .Field(nameof(Option))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<OptionalFormFlow>(nameof(OtherOption))
                .SetActive(state => state.Option == Options.Other))
            .Field(nameof(Name), "What is your name?")
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Confirm("Is this information correct? {*}")
            .Build();

        return built;
    }
}
```

Results:
[image]